# How to load precompiled sourcemaps from node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I have a library, transpiled from babel with precompiled sourcemaps:

```
node_modules/mylib:
index.js
index.js.map
mapTokens.js
mapTokens.js.map
plainObject.js
plainObject.js.map
Translator.js
Translator.js.map
```

How to teach webpack parse this maps, when i use this lib in my projet?
Currently webpack builds sourcemap only for main project, not for libs in node_modules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load library sourcemaps using webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702478/how-to-load-library-sourcemaps-using-webpack)

Comment: Have you solved this issue

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app` please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58964565/1773256) link