# How to load library source maps using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm building two projects with webpack; one is a library for the other.

Is it possible to consume the sourcemaps from my library project when building my wrapper project? I would like the ability to debug my library code from my wrapper UI.

My build works correctly in that the library is built in. The only issue is sourcemaps. The JavaScript I see in the browser debugger is uglified, because sourcemaps are unavailable.

Snippet of my project structure:

```
+-- my-ui/
    +-- dist/
        +-- my-ui.js
        +-- my-ui.js.map
    +-- node_modules/
        +-- my-lib/
            +-- dist/
                +-- bundle.js
                +-- bundle.js.map
```

Snippet from `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'my-ui.js',
        library: 'my-ui',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new Clean('dist'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            inject: true
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: I haven't used it but I *think* [source-map-loader](https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader) is what you're looking for. Assign it as a `preLoader` for the necessary files. This is assuming that `bundle.js` has the source map comment at the end

Comment: Hey @MichelleTilley!

I'm currently trying to use `source-map-loader`, but I've got a `Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined`.

Do you have any idea where it could come from? In my `webpack.config.js` I've got: `devtool: 'source-map'`, `preLoaders: [{ test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }]`,`loaders: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }, { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }, { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-raw-loader' }]`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I finally figured out my issue...

Thanks to @BinaryMuse for the tip on [source-map-loader](https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader). This indeed was the right way to go, though it wasn't working for me initially.

What I eventually realized is that I need to enable the `source-map-loader` for webpack in both "my-lib" *and* "my-ui". Without `source-map-loader` in "my-lib" webpack config, the `source-map-loader` inside "my-ui" errors (with a warning message sadly) because it cannot locate source maps for transitive dependencies of "my-lib". Apparently the source maps are so good that `source-map-loader` is able to peek at all aspects of the dependency tree.

Also of note, I ran into an issue using `source-map-loader` in conjunction with `react-hot-loader`. See, `react-hot-loader` does not include source maps. When `source-map-loader` tries to find them (because it's just scanning everything), it cannot and aborts everything.

Ultimately, I'd like `source-map-loader` to be more fault tolerant, but when set up correctly, it does work!

```js
devtool: 'source-map',
module: {
    preLoaders: [
        {test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'eslint', exclude: /node_modules/},
        {test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'source-map', exclude: /react-hot-loader/}
    ],
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'raect-hot!babel', exclude: /node_modules/}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'm also using react-hot-loader with this setup, and it likely saved me a good deal of time. (as the error you got wasn't very specific!)

Comment: In this case you can just test for map files instead of testing for every js files. Like: `{ test: /\.js\.map$/, loader: 'source-map' }`. This way it doesn't error out on every other file... That's what I did and it solved it to me. But thanks me for pointing to the right direction anyway! :)

Answer (score 3):

My answer is similar to [@Jeff Fairley's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749125) and I had the same directory structure, with the only difference being that I was using `module: { rules: [] }` instead of his `module: { preLoaders: [..], loaders: [...]}`. This is what I had to add to my webpack.config.js file:

```js
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
      }
    ]
  },
```

Then I ran

```sh
npm i -D source-map-loader
```

and I saw the TypeScript source code of the dependency I was using when clicking through tracebacks in Chrome's devtools. See the [Webpack docs for `source-map-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/source-map-loader/).

Comment: worked like a charm for a TypeScript project with another TypeScript project as dependency: https://github.com/livekit/client-sdk-js

Answer (score 1):

I am using `create-react-app` and this is how I Fixed it (without running `eject` cmd)

> Note : If your app is already overriding `webpack config` using `react-app-rewired` you can ignore first three steps.

- `npm i react-app-rewired -D` - This will help you to override `webpack`
  configuration.
- `package.json` - change your scripts, replace `react-scripts` with `react-app-rewired`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  }
```

- `config-overrides.js` - create this file in the parent level of the app.
- `npm i source-map-loader -D` - To load source maps (assuming that your lib's dist has source map file). It doesn't matter which build tool(ex: `Rollup`, `webpack` or `parcel`) you use to generate `sourcemap`.
- Copy below code in `config-overrides.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, env) => {
    // Load source maps in dev mode
    if (env === 'development') {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        use: ['source-map-loader'],
        enforce: 'pre',
      });

      // For `babel-loader` make sure that sourceMap is true.
      config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
        // `create-react-app` uses `babel-loader` in oneOf
        if (rule.oneOf) {
          rule.oneOf.map(oneOfRule => {
            if (
              oneOfRule.loader &&
              oneOfRule.loader.indexOf('babel-loader') !== -1
            ) {
              if (oneOfRule.hasOwnProperty('options')) {
                if (oneOfRule.options.hasOwnProperty('sourceMaps')) {
                  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
                  oneOfRule.options.sourceMaps = true;
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
        return rule;
      });
    }

    return config;
  },
};
```

- Restart your app (if it's already running). `source files` get loaded in different locations, based on path in map file. Check all folders patiently :)

> Note : 
>   1. Your source maps get loaded in one of the folder(ex : `localhost:3000` or `webpack:///` ) based on path it reads from xxx.js.map file.
>   2. If you are using `rollup` for your libs, please make sure you give proper path in the configuration file (output.sourcemapPathTransform ), This will help to load `sourcemaps` in the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any of the **eval** source map options that Webpack provides.

Really that just amounts to setting the right `devtool` option in your `webpack.config.js` for the `my-lib` project.

```
devtool: 'eval',
```

`eval` and `eval-source-map` should both work.

See the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) for the various options.

Comment: this answer is misleading

Comment: How is it misleading?

Comment: ^ Because this configures how source maps are emitted for the library project - but we also want to consume them from an external project making use of this library.

Vice versa for the project - if it defines `devtool` and emits sourcemaps, the code can be mapped to local source but won't include the library mappings.