# debug in chrome and step into original code and not compiled one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, source-maps

Suppose that I work in a project with react.js as a dependency.

Now I add breakpoint in my own code and the breakpoint is triggered in chrome.

Is there any way to step through original lines of code of react library instead of compiled file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot leave a comment because I don't have enough reputation, but what you are looking for is Source Maps.

Here is a Medium article that could be beneficial: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/debug-your-react-app-like-a-ninja-with-source-maps-c63010b3a6e7

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't help because I can see my own code, here I'm talking about others code.

Comment: There is no way to see the original lines of code of a react library, if the library doesn't include source maps. The code is compressed and partially obfuscated and information is lost in that process.

Comment: I have a library called sockjs which include source maps in their build folder, is it possible to open original files in source folder while debugging?

Comment: Which build tool are you using for bundling the code?

Comment: I'm using webpack, I wonder if it's possible if for example there is a file called entry.js in src folder of an npm package and when I'm debugging in chrome, this file happen to be open in my chrome devtools.

Comment: I made it https://stackoverflow.com/a/71687038/2804752 :D